# Decorating text (Bold/Italic) of Label programmatically in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I want to decorate Label text as Bold or Italic or both.

So far to make it work, I'm applying `label.setUIID("BoldItalic_Label")` or setting different UIID in same manner.

But now I want to decorate Label Text programmatically. I've tried mostly all  style properties which can be applied to label text, it doesn't work for me.

Can anybody suggest the workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

Try `label.getUnselectedStyle().setFont(font)`.

You can create the font object using the Font class's factory methods.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir for a suggestion. But I've also tried this way to set the font with different style. `Font existingFont = label.getUnselectedStyle().getFont();  Font newFont = Font.createSystemFont(existingFont.getFace(), Font.STYLE_ITALIC, existingFont.getSize());  label.getUnselectedStyle().setFont(newFont);` This way of setting style is also not working.

Comment: Italic won't necessarily work for all platforms although it should work for this case in the simulator. Is it possible you do something else afterwards like setUIID?